# How to make images move automatically + on mouseover in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, move

How to make images move automatically + on mouseover in CSS/HTML?

For example [Ek Main Aur Ekk Tu Movie Site](http://ekmainaurekktuthemovie.com)

Comment: then tell me how to add that thing in my html page

Answer (score 5):

It's actually really easy to do with CSS3:

```
.moveMe
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #f01;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s;
    -moz-transition: top 2s;
    -o-transition: top 2s;
}

.moveMe:hover
{
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
}
```

This tells the element onHover to transition between the two states of `top` over a period of 2 seconds and 0.3 seconds when the mouse leaves.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/HGjQC/'

As this is a CSS3 technique, the code here will only work in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, any other browser using the Chromium engine [Rockmelt]), Opera and Mozilla browsers.

For IE, yoy'll probably need to use Javascript for now until MS decides to implement more CSS3.

Comment: No, it won't. But the OP can use JS instead.

Comment: What is the difference between -webkit-transition,-moz-transition, and -o-transition? Also, how to you tell the program how far and in what direction to move?

Comment: They are vendor prefixes, they are used to tell each different browser to do the same thing. When these experimental features are standardised, you can remove them and use just the property itself. You set the direction and measurement generally using two classes: so the initial class would have top: 0; and an additional class (that you can switch between using javascript) would has top: 20px;. When the switch occurs, the position transitions from 0 to 10px.

Answer (score 1):

It uses something called parallax effect. I found a jquery plugin that seems to help do this kind of effects. The plugin is called [Plax](http://www.cameronmcefee.com/plax/), here is the [demo](http://www.cameronmcefee.com/plax-demo/)

Answer (score 0):

you could make an invisible div, and then use the query .attr() tag to change the image on hover. I'm not sure I get your question though, because I couldn't find the site that wanted to base yours off of.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use JavaScript, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/HGjQC/2/

Comment: Your example is just a copy/paste of @Kyle's answer. Without the parallax effect.

Comment: hey @bosco thanks for keeping an eye on such an old issue. My answer is actually a fork of Kyle's fiddle. He's option uses pure css while I toggled the class using jQuery.
I'm not sure what you meant by parallax effect, but in his answer the mouseout event had a shorter transition. 
In 10 years retrospect Kyle has the right answer definitely, with a minor comment: the vendor prefixes are not needed any longer. Here an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reyrodrigez/bv5p9xa4/
9 years later reviews FTW ¯\_(ツ)_/¯